# If the libGDX project setup name follows certain formatting conventions, then what is the correct way of specifying the exact title of the app?

Tags: libgdx, naming-conventions, setup-project, naming, conventions

I'm trying to set up my libGDX project from [this](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/libgdx-project-generator-2019-tutorial-eclipse-android-studio/) website. I came across this picture:

[image: libGDX Project Setup Picture]

On the website, under Project Generator > Project Generator Options > Project Name, it says:

> The name of your project. This is usually written out all in lowercase with minus separators. E.g. skull-crushers

If this is the case, then where exactly should I specify the exact title of the game? In this case, where exactly should I specify that I want the exact title to be Skull Crushers (the text that shows below the launcher icon on Android and IoS, the text that shows in the window frame's title on desktop, and the title text of the webpage in an HTML environment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry too much what you call the project. This is only for local files and the project folder name.

What shows up on the website/app can be configured from within the code/gradle files.

Comment: For the desktop app, it's in the main method for the application config.
Android is in a similar place. Idk for the others but it's very easy.